# Cant send images to Mysql Server

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I am having trouble with my code. I am trying to make a upload function to send ads to a database. It simple contains an image. Here is my PHP file

```
<?php
    $servername = ""; //Taken out for stack overflow question
    $username = ""; //Taken out for stack overflow question
    $password = ""; //Taken out for stack overflow question  
    $dbname = ""; //Taken out for stack overflow question

    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if (!$conn)
    {
        echo 'Could not connect';
    }
    else 
    {
        $cf = $_POST['cf']; //Image file 
        $category = $_POST['category']; //Category
        mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO".$category."VALUES(".$cf.")"); //Query
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

If it is syntax, keep in mind, I have no way to debug it. My server on my computer (xampp) no longer works, so I am just uploading it to my online web server and playing it by sight. It shows no errors or debug info.

Here is my "form" it is made by ajax so form tags are removed.

```
            <div class="modal fade chromeModal">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                            <h2>Chrome form</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="imgPreview">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <div role="form" class="form-inline alignButtons">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="category"></label>
                                    <select class="form-control" id="category">
                                        <option id="cat1">Food</option>
                                        <option id="cat2">Software</option>
                                        <option id="cat3">Hardware</option>
                                        <option id="cat4">Home</option>
                                        <option id="cat5">Outdoor</option>
                                        <option id="cat6">Indoor activities</option>
                                        <option id="cat7">Services</option>
                                        <option id="cat8">Other</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="btn btn-primary btn-file">
                                        Upload <input type="file" class="btn btn-primary" id="upload" name="cf" style="display:none;">
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn-default" id="submit">Submit</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And lastly the event listeners

```
chromeOnly.addEventListener("click", function() {
    Notification.requestPermission(function(request) {
        console.log(request);
    });
    $(".chromeModal").modal('show');
    var chromeOnlyData = $('#upload').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://4lifeidiomas.com/smartlead/app/php/sendChrome.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: chromeOnlyData,
        success: function(data)
        {
            var chromeSent = new Notification('Smart Lead Advertisment', {
                icon: 'http://4lifeidiomas.com/smartlead/app/logo.png',
                body: 'Successfully sent to Google Chrome extension!'
            });
        },
        error: function()
        {
            var chromeSentError = new Notification('Smart Lead Advertisment', {
                icon: 'http://4lifeidiomas.com/smartlead/app/logo.png',
                body: 'Error trying to send data to Google Chrome'
            });
        }
    });
}, false);
```

But I cannot get it to work. What am I doing wrong? What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Hi, you should be able to debug it with `$cf = $_POST['cf']; //Image file 
        $category = $_POST['category']; //Category
        mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO".$category."VALUES(".$cf.")"); //Query` change each value to a static value to check if your form is POST-ing correctly.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like your category is missing a name variable. Add a name to identify it so that your POST is able to read this.

```
 <select class="form-control" name="category" id="category">
                                    <option id="cat1">Food</option>
                                    <option id="cat2">Software</option>
                                    <option id="cat3">Hardware</option>
                                    <option id="cat4">Home</option>
                                    <option id="cat5">Outdoor</option>
                                    <option id="cat6">Indoor activities</option>
                                    <option id="cat7">Services</option>
                                    <option id="cat8">Other</option>
                                </select>
```

Comment: Ah okay, and is the Ajax correct as well?

Comment: I see no error with it, try to add a name and see if it updates your database, if not, confirm that the query is updating with the above comment, at least this assures you that is not the php causing the issue.

Comment: Also images will be inputted with my query right? I usually don't upload images into a BLOB I just output them.

Comment: Yup, I don' use BLOB too, I use this for my website's banner, makes it easier to update and change. 

I assume you are inserting the imagelink in to the database, right? and then calling it back somewhere else.

Comment: Yeah basically advertisers can upload their ads, then viewers can see them l later. Once they go to the page or open the browser extension

Comment: Yes. It should work as expected. Haven't seen your code yet, but it should work. Are you able to verify whether this issue is solved first? :)

Comment: Ill let you know in the morn. Its 10:53 I was working all day

Comment: Ill test this out tomorrow

Comment: Sure! Just wanted to confirm whether I was right haha.